# Compilation warnings with BoundChecker using VS2005

Tags: visual-c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2005, devpartner

I am getting following warning when compiling my code to instrument it with Compuware BoundChecker 8.1 in VS2005

1>Compiling...

1>cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/NMbcOn'

1>cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/NMclver:8.0'

1>IDEProject.cpp

1>Linking...

1>NMLINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/NMbcOn'; ignored

1>NMLINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/NMclver:8.0'; ignored

I think, due to above warning, BoundChecker is not reporting runtime errors.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

/NMbcOn is the switch to tell NMCL to use boundschecker instrumentation. CL of course does not know what that switch is and it should have been stripped of by NMCL before calling CL.

/NMclver:8.0 tells NMCL which version of CL you are using which is VS2005. Again this should of been stripped off by NMCL before calling CL.

How are you compiling the project? Are you seeing the headers in the output that show the version of NMCL?

Comment: I am compiling my project using VS2005 IDE. No, it does not show any headers in the output. I think, instead of picking CL, it should use some NMCL similar to as it is using NMLINK instead of LINK. DO you know where to configure NMCL.

Comment: When you turn on Error Detection instrumentation on the tool bar or through the devpartner / Native C/C++ Instrumenation Menu it should use NMCL automatically.